# Using JQuery to do a GET request with POST variables

Tags: jquery, post

I want to call a url from an onclick event and pass it POST variables. I do not want to do this via hidden inputs and a form submit. Of course I want to do this using jquery.

The url will have to be loaded into a popup window.

The question, since I am a jquery newbie, is how?

Comment: Why don't you want to use form submit / hidden input ? I think it's generally advised to do so, because it allows a better maintainability.

Comment: How are hidden fields more maintainable? I don't remember the specific task I wanted to use this for, but I'm pretty sure my reason for not using hidden fields was that all my data was being stored in javascript variables anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`$.post`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) function. This will send an AJAX request to your chosen URL, but unlike a regular form submission, it won't reload or change the current page.

---

Edit responding to comments:
You could fudge it by dynamically creating a form with a hidden input for each variable. Set the form's target to "_blank" and then submit it and that should open your other page in a new window.

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    var $f = $('<form></form>')
        .attr({
            method : 'post',
            target : '_blank',
            action : 'myOtherPage.php'
        })
        .appendTo(document.body)
    ;
    var myHiddenVariables = {
        id : 17,
        name : "Joe Bloggs"
    };
    for (var i in myHiddenVariables) {
        $('<input type="hidden" />')
            .attr({
                name : i,
                value : myHiddenVariables[i]
            })
            .appendTo($f)
        ;
    }
    $f[0].submit();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I looked at that. I don't think I could make it work in this situation. I need to download  a file into a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

The following will make an AJAX post to the server with two parameters. In the callback function it opens a popup and populates it with the returned html.

```
$("#aLink").click(function()
{
    $.post("some_url", {param1:"foo", param2:"bar"}, function(html)
    {
        newWindow= window.open ("","newwindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
        newWindow.document.write(html);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to return false from your click function handler once all is said and done! (To avoid page jumping anywhere)